# Subtracting two plots from each other after shifting one

Tags: plotting, interpolation, list-manipulation

I have the following lists representing energy spectra that need to be subtracted from each other to produce a difference spectrum.

`data1 = ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VfBcE9L5", "Data"][[1]]`

`data2 = ToExpression@Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dFcxfJ4j", "Data"][[1]]`

This is how all the spectra look before the necessary shift (I threw a spline fit through the arrays):

[image]

The problem is that I need to preform an energy shift to the black spectrum *before* the subtraction so that the first peaks line up. I usually construct my difference spectrum array like this:

`diffdata = Transpose[{data1[[1,;;,1]], data1[[1,;;,2]] - data2[[1,;;,2]]}]`

Where the first column is energy and the second column is intensity. I want to energy shift `data2` to line up with `data1` (it's about a -0.35 shift), then subtract the intensity of `data1` from the intensity of `data2`

Since the subtraction occurs based on the position of the elements within the list, any shifting I do to column 1 of `data2` (the energy) will not matter to my difference array. Furthermore, the data point spacing is not homogenous within the spectrum i.e. the data points are more dense in the peak regions than in other regions; however, the point spacing between `data1` and `data2` are identical. Is there any way I can get around this?

My immediate attempt was to do something with `Interpolation`, but I do not know how to subtract the y-values of two interpolated functions from each other. I would then input the energies of `data1` (i.e. `data1[[1,;;,1]]` into the interpolated difference spectrum to get the interpolated intensities of with the corresponding energies.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I always use `TimeSeries` for these kinds of problems, since it avoids having to worry about indices too much, gives you good control over resampling and you have a [whole load of useful functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/TimeSeries.html)

```
dt = 0.05;
{ts1, ts2} = 
 TimeSeries[TimeSeriesResample[#, dt,
  ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}]] & /@ {data1, data2};

ListLinePlot[{Quiet@
 TimeSeriesThread[First[#] - Last[#] &, {TimeSeriesShift[ts2, -0.35], ts1}],
 ts1, ts2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green, Black}]
```

[image: final]

The function `TimeSeriesShift` performs your shift/alignment:

```
ListLinePlot[{TimeSeriesShift[ts2, -0.35], ts1}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Black}]
```

[image: aligned]

`TimeSeriesThread` is used to do shifted data2 minus data1. If you want it the other way around, change `First[#]-Last[#]` to `Last[#]-First[#]`.

Comment: thank you for this very instructive answer +1 :)

Comment: Brilliant! I used `TimeSeriesThread[ Last[#] - First[#] &, {TimeSeriesShift[ts2, -0.35], ts1}]` and threw my `data1` energies in there to get the interpolated intensities as an array.

Answer (score 10):

Because `data1` and `data2` have an extra set of curly brackets, it is necessary to remove the extra set before generating interpolating functions.

```
int1 = Interpolation[Flatten[data1, 1]];
int2 = Interpolation[Flatten[data2, 1]];
```

The difference then can be computed and plotted:

```
Plot[{int1[t], int2[t + .35], int1[t] - int2[t + .35]}, {t, 1105, 1134}]
```

[image]

The difference alone is

[image]

**Addendum**

In answer to the OP's question below, the difference between the two curves can be converted into an interpolation function itself, if desired, by

```
diffdata = FunctionInterpolation[int1[t] - int2[t + .35], {t, 1105, 1133.65}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1, InterpolationPoints -> 5 Length[Flatten[data1, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Can the difference between the two interpolations be an interpolation itself i.e. throw a list into the interpolation to get values? I still need a difference array with the energies in `data1` for further processing.

Comment: Procedure for doing so added to Answer.

Comment: Great info for future reference +1

Answer (score 9):

Using the same variable names. The separation can be approximated using `FindPeaks`. I have used on the distinctive three middle peaks.

```
lp1 = ListPlot[data1, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], 
     Point@(p1 = 
        Extract[data1[[1]], 
         List /@ FindPeaks[data1[[1, All, 2]]][[All, 1]]])}, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
lp2 = ListPlot[data2, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], 
     Point@(p2 = 
        Extract[data2[[1]], 
         List /@ FindPeaks[data2[[1, All, 2]]][[All, 1]]])}, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
diff = Drop[p1, 3] - Drop[p2, 2];
md = Mean[diff[[1 ;; 3]]]
i1 = Interpolation[data1[[1]]];
i2 = Interpolation[data2[[1]]];
pld = Plot[{i1[t], i2[t - md[[1]]], i1[t] - i2[t - md[[1]]]}, {t, 
    1105, 1130}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
Column[{lp1, lp2, pld}]
```

The mean difference in 3 peak locations: {-0.309621, 0.0253712}

[image]

Comment: Nice, though what I really need is for the onset and the tail of the peaks to be roughly aligned.

Comment: @W.Heisenberg perhaps this will facilitate you achieving that desired goal